# Vimeo api image thumbnails ?r=pad

Tags: thumbnails, vimeo

When I retrieve image thumbnails from Vimeo using their api they are have '?r=pad' appended to their url like this:

https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/33677886_100x75.jpg?r=pad

And this causes black bars to appear around image. If you remove r=pad, then image size look fine:

https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/33677886_100x75.jpg

I dont know why this happens. I found a thread here which mentions the same thing: https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:279392

You can test this in api playground:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/167666816

I cant find anything in vimeo documentation about this and why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Pad should only add bars if the image dimensions do not match the video dimensions.

Without the pad you will lose parts of the original video frame.